# background image twitches in chrome when positioned via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote a simple paralax script.

When I scroll using the mouse wheel in Chrome and Internet Explorer the background images are twitching while they are repositioned ... In Firefox it always scrolls perfectly smooth (as it is intended). Is this a performance related problem in the browser? What can I do to prevent this (how can i improve the script maybe)?

Online Example:
http://lab.dev-nook.de/_test/paralax/

CSS:

```
body {
        font:100%/1.5 arial;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        color:#fff;
}
.smplParalax {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
}
.content {
        border-bottom:solid 1px #f00;
        min-height:500px;
}
.content .inner {
        padding:20px;
}
#footerSectionOne {
        background-image:url(paralax/1.jpg);
}
#footerSectionTwo {
        background-image:url(paralax/2.jpg);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="smplParalax content" id="footerSectionOne">
    <div class="inner">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="smplParalax content" id="footerSectionTwo">
    <div class="inner">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
function initParalx(options) {
    if(typeof options == "undefined"){
        var options = {
            'class': 'smplParalax',
            'q': 2
        }
    }

    function _handleParalax(options){
        var relPos = 0;
        $(".smplParalax").each(function() {
            relPos = $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top;
            $(this).css("background-position", "0 " + (relPos / options.q) + "px");
        });
    }

    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
        _handleParalax(options);
    });
}

$(window).ready(function() {
    initParalx({
        'q': 1.5
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `background-attachment: fixed` to create the actual parallax effect, you can check the demo below but you need to fix CSS as you like. However, as you can see scroll is smooth.

```js
function initParalx(options) {
    if(typeof options == "undefined"){
        var options = {
            'class': 'smplParalax',
            'q': 2
        }
    }

    function _handleParalax(options){
        var relPos = 0;
        $(".smplParalax").each(function() {
            relPos = $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top;
            $(this).css("background-position", "0 " + (relPos / options.q) + "px");
        });
    }

    $(window).on("load scroll resize", function() {
        _handleParalax(options);
    });
}

$(window).ready(function() {
    initParalx({
        'q': 1.5
    });
});
```

```css
body {
        font:100%/1.5 arial;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        color:#fff;
  height:100%;
}
.smplParalax {
    height: 100%; 
   position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
.content {
        border-bottom:solid 1px #f00;
       
}
.content .inner {
        padding:20px;
}
#footerSectionOne {
        background-image:url(http://lab.dev-nook.de/_test/paralax/paralax/1.jpg);
        
}
#footerSectionTwo {
        background-image:url(http://lab.dev-nook.de/_test/paralax/paralax/2.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smplParalax content" id="footerSectionOne">
    <div class="inner">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="smplParalax" id="footerSectionTwo">
    <div class="inner">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

Comment: Well the attachment: fixed messes up the paralax but it stoppes the twitching. I'l figure out a way to fix the paralax. Thank you